# Keeping you safe

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

Complete the grid and find a two-word final answer.

> [image: cryptic crossword]

Across

> 1. Ability to move first to northern aristocracy (8)
> 4. Animal to rip a short tail back (5)
> 5. Oral tradition about the origin of Indus river (5)
> 6. Heart of Azerbaijan; first khanate's head, then urban capital (4)
> 7. Exclude a note during overtime (4)
> 8. Turn captain's first military status (5)
> 9. Sea navigation's start in Laos retreat is dependent on time of year (8)

Down

> 2. Capable holding Arizona on fire (6)
> 3. Counselor in front of workable central triumvirate (6)

---

<sub>This puzzle is part of *[Recycling old answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150)*.</sub>

Comment: @Jafe  Your puzzles get easier as I get used to your style.  Your puzzles are always enjoyable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GRID:

> [image: grid]

Thanks @Hexonimo for the hint! The two word answer is found by

> Diagonal Top left to Bottom right is **NATIONAL**
>  Diagonal bottom left to top right is **SECURITY**

1. Ability to move first to northern aristocracy (8)

   > **NO + BILITY**
2. Animal to rip a short tail back (5)

   > **TAPIR**
3. Oral tradition about the origin of Indus river (5)

   > **LO(I)RE**
4. Heart of Azerbaijan; first khanate's head, then urban capital (4)

   > **BA+ K +U**
5. Exclude a note during overtime (4)

   > **O(MI)T**
6. Turn captain's first military status (5)

   > **C + RANK**
7. Sea navigation's start in Laos retreat is dependent on time of year (8)

   > **SEA +SO(N)AL**  (El-Guest beat me to it, but we solved it independently)

Down

2. Capable holding Arizona on fire (6)

   > **ABL(AZ)E**
3. Counselor in front of workable central triumvirate (6)

   > **TROI+ KA**  - Star Trek, The Next Generation Counselor Deanna Troi

Comment: Good answers! Hope mine helped.

Comment: Got it about the same time you did.  "There's a new answer" popped up while I was editing.

Comment: Now the real question is what's the two word final answer...

Comment: @El-Guest I think I see it, Look at the diagonals of the grid

Comment: Thanks @hexomino, that's a fantastic find!!!

Comment: Well done @hexonimo

Answer (score 7):

This one is to fill out @Chris Cudmore's remaining clue:

9. Sea navigation's start in Laos retreat is dependent on time of year (8)

   > SEA + navigation's start (N) in Laos retreat (SO_AL) = dependent on time of year **SEASONAL**.

Found by @Hexomino: the two word answer could be

> NATIONAL SECURITY, found by taking the diagonals of the grid.

when we look at the grid below:

> [image: grid crossword]

@Chris: please feel free to use the final answer and crossword in your solution -- you deserve the checkmark here.

Comment: Just got it.  I promise I didn't look

Comment: Doesn't matter to me, I was just trying to help you out haha! Great job :)